# Classes with basic data and then more, and more data - loading partially?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I really have no idea what to title this so someone PLEASE feel free to edit once you get my drift...

For my example, we have `user` and `book` classes.

Each user is one line in our `user_data` table, each book one line in our `book_data` table, and each user's collection can be queried from the one-to-many `user_book_collection` table.

When I load a user object, I am *certain* I want all the basic data (name, age, location) but I may or may not want to know the user's book collection. I *probably don't* want to know all the basic data for each book in that collection, but occasionally I might.

But I want all of this available if need be...

```
RELATIONSHIP MAP

User
  |-- name
  |-- age
  |-- location
  |-- book collection (ARRAY)
        |-- Great Gatsby
        |-- Grapes of Wrath
        |-- Catch-22
        |-- Huckleberry Finn
              |-- author
              |-- edition
              |-- publisher
              |-- price
```

My current approach is to load the first "tier" of data via the user's constructor. And then if I need to know his collection for something, I have a method pair like this:

```
public function getBookCollection() {
    if (empty($this->_Books)) {
        self::loadBookCollection();
    }
    return $this->_Books;
}

private function loadBookCollection() {
    // query dbase with user's ID
    // load results into $this->_Books array
}
```

The `empty()` check is to avoid repetitive trips to the database to get data for the `$_Books` array by different methods in the class.

I figured this was better than loading the entire massive tree of data whenever I want to just initialize a user object...

This is a simple example, but I think it's clear enough.

My questions are:

**1) is this the normal way of handling such things?** I can imagine situations where this sort of data overlap could just go on and on and on...

**2) is there a better way?**

Thank you, and someone please take a crack at my title!

Comment: I think its a good way to dealing with the problem. You may also look into PHP magic methods like __get() and __set()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is generally called ["Lazy Loading" or "Lazy Initialization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) and is a commonly used programming design to help increase performance by delaying the loading of data until your program needs it (if it does at all). So yes, you're doing it in a sane fashion ;)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the proper terminology - that's always a problem for rookies!